# XForms: how to deal with instance data that changes?

Tags: javascript, xml, xforms, xsltforms

At the moment I am working on an XForms application to mutate XML data. This data comes from a local XML file. The file is exported from another application in a static way and read into the application. The problem is that every time the data changes (the XML structure remains the same). How can I fix this in XForms? I use XSLTForms in my application.

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem - is it that you need to reload the file, when it is overwritten by external application?

Comment: Tambet, that's exactly the problem i have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XSLTForms cannot directly access local data files because Javascript is never allowed to do that for security reasons.

For a local only treatment, it's always possible to run a local HTTP server which can be minimal.

If the data file is changing independantly, there is another problem: according to the client-server architecture, XForms can only periodically try to check the file contents.

-Alain